# Making generic expression generating method in C#

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda

I am constructing an IQueryable query using several methods. The methods are somehow complex, but the problem I want to solve can be extracted and simplified as follows. I have two methods

```
private Expression<Func<T, bool>> CreateExpressionA(string ValueA)
{
  return a => a.PropertyA.ToLower() == ValueA;
}

private Expression<Func<T, bool>> CreateExpressionB(string ValueB)
{
  return a => a.PropertyB.ToLower() == ValueB;
}
```

and what I would rather have is this:

```
private Expression<Func<T, bool>> CreateExpression(??? Selector, string Value)
{
  return a => a.Selector.ToLower() == Value;
}
```

or a similar approach that would allow me to avoid having two same methods with the only difference being in what property of an object is being used there.

Is it possible to do this in some elegant way?

Comment: It's quite easy with reflection, I guess...

Comment: It surely is (as I see in the answers), I just did not know how exactly to write it. But I like the non-reflection answer even more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass in a selector `Func` that returns a `string` property:

```
private Expression<Func<T, bool>> CreateExpression<T>(Func<T, string> selector, string value)
{
    return a => selector(a).ToLower() == value;
}
```

Usage:

```
CreateExpression<MyType>(x => x.PropertyA, "thevalue");
```

Comment: I love this solution. This is exactly what I was looking for, and it works well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use reflection, more precisely the class [PropertyInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) as an argument, but the implementation would be more involved. The method could be implemented as follows.

```
private Expression<Func<T, bool>> CreateExpression(PropertyInfo iInfo, string Value)
{
    return a => (iInfo.GetPropertyValue(a) as string).ToLower() == ValueB;
}
```

However, note that this will work only if the type of the property is `string`, otherwise an additional type parameter could be used.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create the Expression from scratch:

```
private Expression<Func<T, bool>> CreateExpression(string propertyName, string value) {
    ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    MemberExpression property = Expression.Property(param, propertyName);
    var valExpr = Expression.Constant(value);
    var body = Expression.Equal(property, valExpr);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, param);
}
```

Call with:

```
var expression = CreateExpression<TypeOfA>("PropertyA", "ValueForPropertyA");
```

It's a bit off the top of my head, but I think this should at least get you started. Let me know if you need help.